# Facebook Open Graph API Examples - How to get the access token?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Facebook has some great-looking examples of Open Graph requests here:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/examples/

The problem is that since I don't have an access token, most of the examples just return

```
{
   "error": {
      "message": "An active access token must be used to query information about the current user.",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 2500
   }
}
```

I understand access tokens, but how do I get the token so that I can experiment with these example requests?

Comment: Access tokens are obtained when your app registers and a user logs in with the facebook api graph. If you're writing an app of some sort, you can get the access token from there and copy that over. I don't believe there's a way to get an access token another way. Here's the doc, you might find something in there https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/

Answer (score 48, accepted):

#### As long as you only want to test...

Use the [Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer) to generate a token with the permissions you want.

[image: Selection Permissions pop-up]

*Don't hesitate to select all of them.*

Then, just copy/paste the token at the end of each `graph.facebook.com` URL. For instance:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v1.0/me/friends?access_token=<ACCESS_TOKEN>
```

---

#### The day you want to get the access taken for an app...

Start by reading [this doc](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/).

Comment: `https://graph.facebook.com/v1.0/me/friends?access_token=<what I get from the graph explorer>`, I get denied